# How to extract img element out of this using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do I get img element out of this:

```
<td><img src="blah" /></td>
```

Thanks.

edit: what I mean is, the above is what I have when I loop through my each statement for each iteration and I want to get rid of the     `<td></td>`.  I'm not searching the entire document.

Further edit: Here is more code. I tried to cut to the heart of the problem but didn't explain it well enough.

```
$(this).closest('tr').children().each(function(){
//some code

        });
```

That is my each function which gets all the td elements of a table row. In the case of text I can use the text() function to get the text, but when it is

```
    <td><img /></td>
```

I don't know how to get the img out. Does that help explain?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very vague question. Without more information, the answer could be as simple as `$("img");`

Comment: are you looking to extract `img` inside a `td`? Or `img` inside a `td` with `src="blah"` or.. ? Please be more specific :s

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: *"...I want to get rid of the <td></td>"* And do what? `td` is only valid within `tr`, and `img` cannot be the direct child of a `tr` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Re your *further* edit**: Use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
$(this).closest('tr').children().each(function(){
    // Get all `img` elements that are in this cell
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
});
```

---

**Older answers before the question was clear**:

Without more context, it's hard to answer really well, but basically, use the [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) function (usually aliased as `$()`) with a CSS selector. So that might be:

```
var img = $("td img");
```

or only children

```
var img = $("td > img");
```

But note in both cases that you'll get **all** `img` elements that are descendants (first example) or direct children (second example) of `td` elements.

Additionally, in both cases above, you'll get a jQuery object which wraps a set of matching elements. To get at the actual underlying DOM elements, index into the object. So for instance, this will give you the very first `img` element that's a descendant of a `td` element in your document:

```
var rawImgElement = $("td img")[0];
```

...and if there aren't any, it'll be `undefined.`

---

Re your edit:

> ...I want to get rid of the `<td></td>`

It's still *very* unclear what you're trying to achieve. Here's an example that moves all `img` elements out of a table, putting them after it (since of course, you can't just move the `img` elements out of the `td` elements, because `img` cannot be a direct child of `tr`).

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="blah1.png"></img></td>
<td><img src="blah2.png"></img></td>
<td><img src="blah3.png"></img></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var $myTable = $("#myTable");
    $("td > img").each(function() {
        var $img = $(this),
            $td = $img.parent();
        $img.insertAfter($myTable);
    });
});
```

...of course, then the table may be empty, and you may need to remove rows, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but is there a way to do this in the style of my code?

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'll include more code in my future questions.

Answer (score 0):

This will refer to the image tag:

```
$("td img")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something for all td to manipulate something

```
$('#table td').each(function() {
var img;
img = $(this).find('img');
alert(img.attr('src'));
});
```